# How to iterate over all request headers in webapp RequestHandler using python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need to iterate over all request header objects and print it in App Engine. I get error when trying to use for cycle. How to do that correctly?

```
class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        for e in self.request.headers:
            self.request.headers(e + "<br />")
```

I get error: `AttributeError: EnvironHeaders instance has no __call__ method`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Error is in `self.request.headers(e + "<br />")` line. You are trying to call the `request.headers` method.

I check the online help and found that `self.request.headers` is `dict` like object. You can check in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingwebapp

To iterate over the `headers` you can use `self.request.headers.items()` or `self.request.headers.keys()`

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean `self.response.write()`:

```
class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        for e in self.request.headers:
            self.response.write(e + "<br />")
```